# AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'loads'

Tags: python, json, list

I'm trying to extract json data from a multiple URLs withe code below but it throws an error as mentioned on the title.
However, when using only one URL the code works.

Any help is appreciated.

```
import urllib, json, time, csv

arr_ids = ['611', '1564', '1565', '1561', '712', '779', '118', '707', '706', '711', '155', '713', '710', '607', '609', '592', '739', '589', '608', '606', '569', '570', '612', '587', '567', '591', '564', '563', '566', '565', '568', '588', '1561', '1387', '1388', '1575', '1567', '1577', '1568', '152', '154', '153', '1203', '1204', '708', '709', '1576', '780', '781', '1573', '1574', '782', '121', '120', '1562', '1385', '1386', '1563']
convert_list = [['date_and_time','val']]

for arr_id in arr_ids:
      url = "http://xxxyyyyx.com/predict/dataloc.php?param=rv&dfrm=01/24/2017&dto=01/25/2017&numloc=1&data24=0&locs[]="+arr_id
      response = urllib.urlopen(url)
      data = json.loads(response.read())
      for key in data:
            station_name = key
            json_data = data[station_name]
            for json in json_data:
                  epoch_time = json[0]/1000 
                  formatted = time.strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S', time.localtime(epoch_time))
                  val = json[1]
                  new_list = [formatted,val]
                  convert_list.append(new_list)

            with open(station_name+".csv", "wb") as f:
                writer = csv.writer(f)
                writer.writerows(convert_list)
```

Thrown Error:

> Traceback (most recent call last):   File
>   "C:\Users\acer\Downloads\getwl_rv\json2csv\json2csv.py", line 9, in
>   
>       data = json.loads(response.read()) AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'loads'

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`for json in json_data:`

In this line, you've overwritten `json` module name.

Answer (score 3):

You've overwritten the module you imported

```
for json in json_data:
```

Try not to name your variables by modules or built in functions